# Error al consumir API con Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, api, rest

Estoy intentando consumir una API para obtener la ubicacion del cliente a la hora de acceder al sitio, gracias a la API `http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=xx.xx.xx.x`

Si yo ingreso a esta URL efectivamente me muestra en JSON los datos para mi IP.

Lo que busco:

1. Obtener mi direccion IP para poder agregarle esa direccion a la URL de la API.
2. Lograr acceder a los datos de mi JSON.

Lo que he intentado:

1. Para obtener la IP utilizo ipify.org y no me muestra ningun problema

   ```
   $.getJSON('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', function(data){
     var $ip= data.ip;
     console.log($ip);
   });
   ```
2. Para mostrar mi JSON en consola he intentado con Promesas pero me muestra en consola 'TypeError: Failed to fetch' como info, y me muestra como ERROR>

> Mixed Content: The page at
> 'https://misitio.com/miArchivo.php' was loaded over HTTPS,
> but requested an insecure resource
> 'http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip=xx.xx.xx.x'. This request has
> been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Entiendo que es porque mi URL es http y no https, pero con HTTPS el link no me funciona.

```
    const url = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip='+$ip;

      fetch(url)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
      console.log(data)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

*Codigo:

```
<script>
$.getJSON('https://api.ipify.org?format=json', function(data){

    var $ip= data.ip;
    const url = 'http://www.geoplugin.net/json.gp?ip='+$ip;

    fetch(url)
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

    console.log($ip);
});

</script>
```

Agradeceria cualquier comentario.

Saludos,

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro. Tu sitio está bajo un protocolo `https`, significa que es más seguro porque los datos que sean enviados desde tu sitio irán cifrados. En cambio, el sitio de la API que quieres usar está bajo un protocolo `http` el cual es menos seguro, porque los datos no viajan cifrados y pueden ser interceptados en el camino. Por defecto, en un sitio `https` toda petición o inclusión de archivo con protocolo `http` es bloqueada (incluso si se refiere al mismo dominio) y no conviene recurrir a trucos para hacerlo funcionar. Es un asunto de seguridad. ...

Comment: La solución es: 1. Usar la versión `https` de la API, si la tiene. 2. Si no la tiene, cambia a otra API. Hoy día, una API que se respete usaría el protocolo `https`. De lo contrario, podrías estar expuesto a un serio riesgo de seguridad. Para más detalles puedes leer [este artículo](https://web.dev/fixing-mixed-content/).

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano, estoy buscando la API en su version https. Nuevamente gracias por tus comentarios.